# Rectangle not using containg correct bounds when using getHeight(), and getWidth()

Tags: java, height, width, jpanel

I have been going in circles trying to figure out why this is not working. I have a rectanlge, it is positioned at 0,0. And is 1/3 of getHeight, and 1/3 of getWidth(), for height and width respectively. I have a mouse event that "captures" the x and y cordinates. When I use the "rectangle".contains(the x and y of the mouse)

****EDIT: When i check where the mouse clicks it always comes back as 0,0 ****

Here is some of my code:

```
package com.blackattack.tictactoe;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TicTacToePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    Graphics2D g2d;
    Rectangle[] bounds = new Rectangle[9];
    TicTacToeLogic board = new TicTacToeLogic();
    int STATE = 0;
    final int PLAYING = 0;
    final int LOSS = 1;
    final int WIN = 2;
    Win w = new Win(false, "e");



    public TicTacToePanel() {
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        bounds[0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);

        bounds[1] = new Rectangle(getWidth()/3, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
        bounds[2] = new Rectangle((getWidth()/3)*2, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);

        bounds[3] = new Rectangle(0, getHeight()/3, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
        bounds[4] = new Rectangle(getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
        bounds[5] = new Rectangle((getWidth()/3)*2, getHeight()/3, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);

        bounds[6] = new Rectangle(0, getHeight()/3, (getWidth()/3)*2, getHeight()/3);
        bounds[7] = new Rectangle(getWidth()/3, (getHeight()/3)*2, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
        bounds[8] = new Rectangle((getWidth()/3)*2, (getHeight()/3)*2, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
        if(w.didWin && w.who.equals("x")){
            STATE = WIN;
        }
        if(w.didWin && w.who.equals("o")){
            STATE = LOSS;
        }

        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(STATE == PLAYING) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.drawLine(getWidth() / 3, 0, getWidth() / 3, getHeight());
        g2d.drawLine((getWidth() / 3) * 2, 0, (getWidth() / 3) * 2, getHeight());
        g2d.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 3, getWidth(), getHeight() / 3);
        g2d.drawLine(0, (getHeight() / 3) * 2, getWidth(),
                (getHeight() / 3) * 2);

        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        if(board.board[0].equals("x")) {
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
            g2d.drawLine(getWidth()/3, 0, 0, getHeight()/3);
        }

        }

    }



    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         int x = getX();
          int y = getY();

          // check which "bounds" contains the mouse click?
          for (int i = 0; i < bounds.length; i++) {
             if (bounds[i].contains(e.getPoint())) {
                System.out.println("Point " + x + " " + y + " contains mouse");
             }
          }
          repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

          }






    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }



}
```

Some theories I have had are:

- Calling getHeight/Width during paintComponent doesn't work, but it works perfectly when I draw the lines
- I have places the values in the wrong places when creating the rectanlge, but i doubled checked that.
- I have tried playing around with the code, but no luck

Thank You,

Andrew

PS here is a [sscce](http://pscode.org/sscce.html):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mainGUI extends JFrame {

    TicTacToePanel tic = new TicTacToePanel();

    public mainGUI() {
        super("Tic Tac Toe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(900, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        add(tic);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class TicTacToePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        Graphics2D g2d;
        Rectangle[] bounds = new Rectangle[9];
        TicTacToeLogic board = new TicTacToeLogic();
        int STATE = 0;
        final int PLAYING = 0;
        final int LOSS = 1;
        final int WIN = 2;
        Win w = new Win(false, "e");



        public TicTacToePanel() {
            super();
            addMouseListener(this);

        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            bounds[0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);

            bounds[1] = new Rectangle(getWidth()/3, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
            bounds[2] = new Rectangle((getWidth()/3)*2, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);

            bounds[3] = new Rectangle(0, getHeight()/3, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
            bounds[4] = new Rectangle(getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
            bounds[5] = new Rectangle((getWidth()/3)*2, getHeight()/3, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);

            bounds[6] = new Rectangle(0, getHeight()/3, (getWidth()/3)*2, getHeight()/3);
            bounds[7] = new Rectangle(getWidth()/3, (getHeight()/3)*2, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
            bounds[8] = new Rectangle((getWidth()/3)*2, (getHeight()/3)*2, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
            if(w.didWin && w.who.equals("x")){
                STATE = WIN;
            }
            if(w.didWin && w.who.equals("o")){
                STATE = LOSS;
            }

            g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            if(STATE == PLAYING) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
            g2d.drawLine(getWidth() / 3, 0, getWidth() / 3, getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine((getWidth() / 3) * 2, 0, (getWidth() / 3) * 2, getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 3, getWidth(), getHeight() / 3);
            g2d.drawLine(0, (getHeight() / 3) * 2, getWidth(),
                    (getHeight() / 3) * 2);

            g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
            if(board.board[0].equals("x")) {
                g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth()/3, getHeight()/3);
                g2d.drawLine(getWidth()/3, 0, 0, getHeight()/3);
            }

            }

        }



        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
             int x = getX();
              int y = getY();

              // check which "bounds" contains the mouse click?
              for (int i = 0; i < bounds.length; i++) {
                 if (bounds[i].contains(e.getPoint())) {
                     board.changeState(i, "x");
                    System.out.println("Point " + x + " " + y + " contains mouse");
                 }
              }
              repaint();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

              }






        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }




}


    public class TicTacToeLogic {

        String[] board = { "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e" };

        public TicTacToeLogic() {

        }

        public void changeState(int pos, String val) {
            board[pos] = val;
        }

        public void aiPlayerChoose() {
            boolean ready = true;
            if(isWin().who.equals("x") && isWin().didWin){
                ready=false;
            }
            while (ready) {
                Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
                int which = r.nextInt(8);
                if (board[which].equals("e")) {
                    board[which] = "o";
                    ready = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public Win isWin() {
            // o
            if (board[0].equals("x") && board[1].equals("x")
                    && board[2].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            if (board[3].equals("x") && board[4].equals("x")
                    && board[5].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            if (board[6].equals("x") && board[7].equals("x")
                    && board[8].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            // o
            if (board[0].equals("o") && board[1].equals("o")
                    && board[2].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }
            if (board[3].equals("o") && board[4].equals("o")
                    && board[5].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }
            if (board[6].equals("o") && board[7].equals("o")
                    && board[8].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }
            // x
            if (board[0].equals("x") && board[4].equals("x")
                    && board[8].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            if (board[2].equals("x") && board[4].equals("x")
                    && board[6].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            // o
            if (board[0].equals("o") && board[4].equals("o")
                    && board[8].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }
            if (board[2].equals("o") && board[4].equals("o")
                    && board[6].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }
            // x
            if (board[0].equals("x") && board[3].equals("x")
                    && board[6].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            if (board[1].equals("x") && board[4].equals("x")
                    && board[7].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            if (board[2].equals("x") && board[5].equals("x")
                    && board[8].equals("x")) {
                return new Win(true, "x");
            }
            // x
            if (board[0].equals("o") && board[3].equals("o")
                    && board[6].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }
            if (board[1].equals("o") && board[4].equals("o")
                    && board[7].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }
            if (board[2].equals("o") && board[5].equals("o")
                    && board[8].equals("o")) {
                return new Win(true, "o");
            }

            return new Win(false, "e");
        }



    }

    public class Win {

        boolean didWin = false;
        String who = "";

        public Win(boolean i, String s) {
            didWin = i;
            who = s;

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainGUI app = new mainGUI();
    }

}
```

Comment: Suggestions: 1) pepper your code with println statements to see the state of your variables at various location in the program. 2) don't do program logic in a paint or paintComponent method. For instance this method is never one where you should decide if a game wins or not. It is for painting and painting **only**. 3) Use your arrays to help you. If you took full advantage of your arrays, you'd be able to eliminate over 1/2 the code above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels time to clean up some code!

Comment: I would suggest if you don't already do so to get a good IDE that allows for easy implementation of debugging with breakpoints.  Add a breakpoint at the first line of paintComponent and check what each value ACTUALLY is as the code walks through the program.  What's probably happening is what you expect the values to be are simply not so at the time.  If you can walk through the code, you can check each and every value as you go through it.

Comment: @Asaf I am using eclipse and have used break points I assume eclipse should do fine

Comment: @AndrewDelgadillo Yeah, it's what I use personally.  If you are able to see the values and still can't figure out what's wrong I recommend you add the extra information to the question.  Also try the suggestion in the answer below.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson alright I dide but it really isn't so short...

Answer (score 1):

For instance, just add this to your mouse listener (and again most of the code in the mouse listener can be compressed with smarter use of arrays) so you can see what happens when you click in a square:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  int x = getX();
  int y = getY();

  // check which "bounds" contains the mouse click?
  for (int i = 0; i < bounds.length; i++) {
     if (bounds[i].contains(e.getPoint())) {
        System.out.println("Point " + i + " contains mouse");
     }
  }
```

As an aside: I'd trap the mousePressed event not the mouseClicked event since the latter can miss presses.

Comment: @Andrew: this code tells me that you've got a problem with defining the boundaries of bounds[6].  I suggest that you set your bounds with a for loop so that the code only has to be written once and correclty for all rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for that. When I print out the x and y of the click it always says 0,0 which is pretty odd. Im thinking that something is screwed up with the mouse Listener

Comment: It' doesn't print 0,0 for me, but shows me which bounds object was clicked. I see what you did, it's not just 6 but perhaps 8 as well. Again, use the array, use a for loop, fix the code.

Comment: I have replaced the mouseClicked with the for loop. I see how that works, but what do you mean by "not just 6 but perhaps 8 as well"?